# CPU request on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, containers, amazon-eks

I have a resource block for my pod like -

> ```
>    resources:
>     limits:
>       cpu: 3000m
>       memory: 512Mi
>     requests:
>       memory: 512Mi
> ```

does it by default take request allocation for CPU (i.e 3000m) which is mentioned in resource limits (3000m). Because in my case it taking 3000m as default cpu in request even though I have not mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you observed is correct, K8s will assign the requests.cpu that matches the limits.cpu when you only define the limits.cpu and not the requests.cpu. Official document [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/#if-you-specify-a-cpu-limit-but-do-not-specify-a-cpu-request).

Answer (score 1):

**sourced from kubernetes documentation**

If you specify a CPU limit for a Container but do not specify a CPU request, ***Kubernetes automatically assigns a CPU request that matches the limit***. Similarly, if a Container specifies its own memory limit, but does not specify a memory request, ***Kubernetes automatically assigns a memory request that matches the limit***